# How to check for a " " in assembly

Tags: string, loops, assembly, ascii, mips

just as the title says i want to look for a " " in a string. My issue is that in my loop, i need to check the length of a string a user inputs. so with the code

```
li $v0, 8
la $a0, str1           #str1: .spcae 8 is in the data area. 
addi $a1,$zero,8   
syscall
```

The issue is if i enter, lets say car. car is only three characters, so there are still 4 more open spaces plus the \0 at the end. my loop counts those 4 remaining spaces as part of the string. How do I break out of my loop when it encounters that first empty space? (no i will not be entering a space in the word like "im here")

here is my loop that works just fine for checking for the \0 but not the empty space.

```
length: add $t2, $a0, $t0 # $t2 = &array[j]
 lb $t2, 0($t2) # $t2 = array[j]
 beq $t2, $0, done # end of string?
 addi $t0, $t0, 1 # j = j+1
 j length
```

im hoping there is some way i could store a " " string into a register and check for that somehow,(rest of code compiles fine but let me know if you want to see it, don't think it would help to much)

Comment: What *is* a string and how does it differ from (and relate to) a character? Which register would "contain" a string? How?

Comment: Um, a string is ascii characters in code. its different from a character because a character can be used differently than a string. although characters make up a string.

lol were you using my question to ask a question?

Comment: Okay, so how can 'a " " string' be stored into a register? It can't (at least not directly), but a *space character* [represented by a certain small integer value can be](http://www.asciitable.com/). Then the task becomes "terminate the loop when the_character is equal to the_value_for_space". Anyway, the string should probably immediately be ended with \0 instead of having this extra white-space padding. (Most designs treat trailing white-space differences as different strings.)

Comment: hey,so i got it to work for the most part, i just need to figure out how to add 0x20 to the end of a use inputted string

Comment: `.space` doesn't fill a sequence of bytes with space characters (ASCII 32). It fills them with 0 by default.